# Disable xsl:comment in XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XSLT file littered with comments such as the following:

```
<xsl:comment>Entering shipping block</xsl:comment>
```

Is there a way to explicity disable these comments so that they aren't output at runtime in production? The output of the XSLT file is shown in a public API, so while it is useful for debugging, I would rather be able to switch it off.

The only way I can think of is to have a flag that is set in development mode to turn on the comments:

```
<xsl:if test="$enableDebug='true'">
    <xsl:comment>Entering shipping block</xsl:comment>
</xsl:if>
```

Is there another way?

(I'm using XSLT 2.0.)

Comment: There is a `use-when` attribute https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conditional-inclusion but I think you would need to use XSLT 3.0 and a static parameter to be able to write `<xsl:comment use-when="$enableDebug">...</xsl:comment>`, in XSLT 2.0 you can apply the `use-when` attribute but I don't think there is access to parameters in the expression supplied.

Comment: You might be able to use `use-when="system-property('debug')"` but it's rather processor dependent whether and how you can set your own system properties.

Comment: Another possibility would be to apply a second XSLT to the result of the first XLST that strips out all comments from the XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay, or provide `xsl:evaluateXsl` that takes a tree and evaluates it as an XSLT stylesheet :)

Answer (score 1):

**Just include this transformation step in your deployment to production:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comment()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You my even not specify any `indent` attribute on `<xsl:output>` in case readability is not a goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable `verbose` at the very top of your XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:variable name="verbose">1</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
        ...
```

and wrap your comments in `<xsl:if>` like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$verbose">
    <xsl:comment>Applying the template...</xsl:comment>
</xsl:if>
```

If you then want to temporarily deactivate the comments, just remove the `1` from the `verbose` variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="verbose"></xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Oops! I just noticed you already had this idea and asked for a different way.

Comment: Also, using a result-tree-fragment variable as a boolean is pretty dodgy. Why not use a boolean variable `<xsl:variable name="verbose" select="true()"/>`? Relying on boolean() of an RTF being true and boolean() of a zero-length string being false is asking for trouble.